# Apache Ignite C#.Net thin client SSL authentication

Tags: c#, client, ignite, thin

I have Apache Ignite Thin client used in C#.Net (NugetPackage Apache.Ignite --version 2.11.0-alpha20210225). When I use below SSL configuration, I'm getting below exception. If I say "SkipServerCertificateValidation=true", it works fine.

Any suggestions will be appreciated..

C#.Net Code:

```
var cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration
        {
            Endpoints = new[] {"127.0.0.1:10800"}, //worked endPoint
            SslStreamFactory = new SslStreamFactory
            {
                CertificatePath = "C:/OpenSSL/rsh_client.pfx",
                CertificatePassword = "RSH",
                SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                //SkipServerCertificateValidation = true. It works if I enable this code
            }
        };
        var ignite = Ignition.StartClient(cfg);
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.SslStreamFactory.Create(Stream stream, String targetHost)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.GetSocketStream(Socket socket, IgniteClientConfiguration cfg, String host)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration, EndPoint endPoint, String host, Nullable`1 version, Action`1 topVerCallback, Marshaller marshaller)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.Connect(SocketEndpoint endPoint)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.GetNextSocket()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.ConnectDefaultSocket()
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration config, Marshaller marsh, TransactionsClient transactions)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient..ctor(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
   at Apache.Ignite.Core.Ignition.StartClient(IgniteClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
   at Ignite.Client.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\RSH\dotnet\Ignite\Client\Program.cs:line 61
```

Server-config.xml:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
                <property name="port" value="10800"/>
                <property name="sslEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sslContextFactory">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.ssl.SslContextFactory">
                <property name="keyStoreFilePath" value="C:/apache-ignite-2.9.1-bin/security/server.keystore.jks"/>
                <property name="keyStorePassword" value="RSH"/>
                <property name="trustStoreFilePath" value="C:/apache-ignite-2.9.1-bin/security/server.truststore.jks"/>
                <property name="trustStorePassword" value="RSH"/>
                <property name="protocol" value="TLSv1.2"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Server side exception:

```
[14:42:19,955][WARNING][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-4-#45][ClientListenerProcessor] Client disconnected abruptly due to network connection loss or because the connection was left open on application shutdown. [cls=class o.a.i.i.util.nio.GridNioException, msg=Failed to decode SSL data: GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=DirectNioClientWorker [super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=4, bytesRcvd=304, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=304, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-4, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1622106739953, hashCode=264174266, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-4-#45]]], writeBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=65536 cap=65536], readBuf=java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=31 lim=31 cap=65536], inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:51412, createTime=1622106739772, closeTime=0, bytesSent=2415, bytesRcvd=304, bytesSent0=2415, bytesRcvd0=304, sndSchedTime=1622106739772, lastSndTime=1622106739900, lastRcvTime=1622106739953, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerNioMessageParser, directMode=true], SSL filter], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
[14:42:29,909][WARNING][grid-timeout-worker-#30][ClientListenerNioListener] Unable to perform handshake within timeout [timeout=10000, remoteAddr=/127.0.0.1:51412]
```

Comment: Where do you get the certificate? Validation will fail for self-signed certificates, you need a real one for this to work without `SkipServerCertificateValidation`.

Comment: What version of Net is client using?  Make sure it is Net 4.7.2 or later and that TLS option in project is set to Operating System.  TLS you can either use Net or Operating System.  Do not think Net will support Kafka.  See following for setting up kafka : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/kafka/apache-kafka-ssl-encryption-authentication?force_isolation=true

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn I created certificates using OpenSSL. I've created my own CA, signed my CSRs. Imported signed certificate, CA certificate in Ignite trust store as well I've imported in Windows Certificate Manager (Local Computer level)

Comment: @jdweng I use .Net core version 3.1.408

Comment: I knew you were going to say that.  I starting to understand better what Core is all about.  Microsoft wanted a version of Net that would run on Linux server, Mobile devices (Win10), and Windows.   Net 4.7.2 added feature to default to OS for TLS instead of Net (with option to use Net).  Kafka is a Linux encryption method.  So you need to build in Net 4.7.2 and then target Core 3.1 to get Kafka to work.  Also you need to configure you machine per my last link for Kafka on client.  I think the issue is on the client side.

Comment: @jdweng you mean I should move out from .Net core and use .Net 4.7.2 instead? By this change IgniteClient can access Windows Trust store?

Comment: In VS you should be using Net 4.7.2 or later and then in the project settings set the target to Core 3.1.  The stores are in the user tmp space which is where a browser gets the certificates and any application like c# app.